# How to add dll files to Git Repository

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

I'm using bitbucket to host my git repository. 
I've added a new folder called ExtLibs and added bunch of dlls. However they do not show up in SourceTree when I try to check in those files.

How do I add a folder with (dll) files to repo?

I'm using .gitignore from [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore) (c#/VS2013)

[image]

Comment: When you add a new file to Git you need to tell Git to start tracking it. SourceTree should list the new files you added under "unstaged files".

Comment: how do i tell it?. I've created a new folder /ExtLibs and copied some dll into it. But no changes show up in SourceTree to commit. SourceTree doens't track that folder or files inside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add new files to Git, you have to tell it to start tracking the new files. This can be done by using the `git add` command.

In your case SourceTree should detect when new files are added. The new files will be shown in the "Unstaged files" pane. You can toggle the pane if you can't see it.

[image]

Comment: ARRR! this drove me crazy. Thank you :)

Answer (score 7):

Using sourceTree : tools -> option, choose Git tab -> Edit file 'global ignore list' -> remove line *.dll

-- maybe it can help --

Answer (score 4):

I can't find a (C#/VS2013) `.gitignore` in the link you posted. But I guess the file you are using has a section that tells to ignore all DLL-files:

Something like `*.dll` or `**\*.dll`

You have to remove that part from your file. Or you can add: `!ExtLibs\*.dll` if you want to just add the DLLs in the ExtLibs-folder.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this answer to help someone like me.
I wanted to add only one DLL.

Go to the folder. For example the packages folder for the Visual Studio C# project.

run this

```
git add <filename.dll> -f
```

Using this command, you are not required to update the .gitignore and it will not add other files.

Answer (score 0):

In SourceTree, from Show Only dropdown box, choose Ignored files option and it will list all files under Unstaged files section, select your file and click on Stage Selected button.

[image]

Then choose the Pending files option from Show Only dropdown box and your file will show there.